# How to create a foreign key in my DBAdapter class?

Tags: android, database, foreign-keys

I have created a database adapter with all the tables that I have in my database however as you all can see the name_id exist in 3 tables. But it is a foreign key in the CREATE_TABLE_LIKES and CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES so is there any way that I can make it be foreign key in the 2 tables? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Codes for the database adapter:

```
 package main.page;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AnniversaryDBAdapter
{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AllTables";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = " create table buddiesList(name_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LIKES = " create table likes(name_id integer primary key autoincrement,likes text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES = " create table dislikes(name_id integer primary key autoincrement, dislikes text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS = "create table events(date_id integer primary key autoincrement, name_id text not null, date text not null, title_id text not null, starttime text not null, endtime text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TITLE = "create table titles(title_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null, image text not null);";

    private final Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public AnniversaryDBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }




private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LIKES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TITLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion+", which will destroy all old data");

        onCreate(db);

    }

}


public AnniversaryDBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    this.db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    this.DBHelper.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a foreign key with auto-increment, as it should always be a value exists in another table, it may be simpler to create a new column just to make this relationship.